# Search in a file and display using Javascript

Tags: javascript, search

I need to search in a file for an expression entered in a input field, and return the result in a div with *n* number of characters before and after and the expression in bold.
I don't know once I used the search() function of javascript how to return the results, knowing that the result of that command is the position.
So far I only have this:

```
var length = expr.legth;/*get the length of the expression searched*/
var indexString = docSearched.search(expression);/*get the position of the expression in the document*/
```

and now I would need something like that:

```
var el = document.getElementById('content'); 
    el.innerHTML = docSearched[indexString];/*display the all the occurence of the searched expression*/
```

Comment: 1+ for No-one's going to write it for you.

Comment: I would gladly help you, but the question is vague, I don't exactly understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I need to look for a certain expression in a file and display all the occurences of that expression.
for exemple:
file.txt:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
expression searched:
ipsum

and I need to display in a div the expression and 5 characters before and after:
orem ipsum dolo

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
string.substring(beginning,end);
```